# Override Network Administration Settings

Tags: networking, administrator, group-policy

Is there a way to override settings set by a network administrator for Windows? I'm having all kinds of problems updating and sharing WiFi because it's "been disabled by the network administrator."

I'm using a personal computer, and I do have administrator access on the machine, so I don't see why I shouldn't be able to edit this stuff. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: sounds like a PC that is apart of a domain so you are at the mercy of the administrator and group policy, how about downloading a 3rd party program that accomplishes the same thing you are trying to do, I assume you will be able to install it since you have local admin rights on the PC.

Comment: just because ypu are logging into an admin account doesn't mean your an admin of the domain./

Comment: So there's no way to override group policies, even with administrator access to the machine? I'd been reading that I could manually edit group policy stuff, but that doesn't appear to be working. Maybe I'll just have to email my boss about this...

Comment: To add to @Ramhound's comment; being an administrator on the computer is NOT the same thing as Network Administrator. For obvious reasons, as a user on the domain, can not bypass network policies. You will need to get permission from the Network Administrator to do what you are trying.

Comment: @Rev - Of course there is a way. You just need to log into a administrator domain account, what your logging into, is a normal network account which is a local administrator account.  Make sure you have permission to do what your trying to do.